# How to hide scroll bar but want to it keep working

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

Here is code

```
#scroll{
overflow-y:scroll;
max-height:500px;
width:267px;}
```

I explored it on Stackoverflow and i got many answers but they were explained with two conatiners in HTML but i have only one div and want to apply it on that. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You should look into parent child approach as it is the recommended one. Give your element scroll bars, wrap it in a
containing element, and make the containing element element smaller, and give it:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

In your current scenario you can do this pure CSS.
Hide scroll bars in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari).

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

Hide scrollbars in IE 10+.

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Hide scrollbars in Firefox, but it has been deprecated.

```
.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk1e4qqv/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your time .. I think it is for whole webpage . But i need it for a specific Div. Actually I'm using it with drop down menu so need to apply it on drop down section where the options are lot of -- Here is screenshot please have a look --   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0w8jyKHNbVFMXJDdzU2RFdOSW8/view?usp=sharing